# jQuery(window).width() giving me 'not a function' error

Tags: jquery, width

This script was working fine a while back but for some reason now gives an error "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).width is not a function"

How would I correct this?

Thank you.

```js
<script>
var boxWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    // if mobile then we will keep width @ 100% else only 50%
if ( boxWidth > 768 ) { 
  boxWidth = boxWidth * 0.50;
  console.log( boxWidth );
    }
else boxWidth = boxWidth;
  
    jQuery('#menu-open').on('click', function(){
      jQuery('#slider').css('width' , boxWidth);
      jQuery('#slider').toggleClass('open');
    return false;  
    })
  
    jQuery('#menu-close').on('click', function(){
      jQuery('#slider').css('width' , 0 );
      jQuery('#slider').toggleClass('open');
    return false;  
    })
</script>
```

I am trying to find the width of the browser window and make a size for the overlay menu either to cover 100% or only x% if larger screen.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using wordpress with divi theme and jQuery is bundled in - how would I get the version?

Answer (score 3):

It seems correct. Maybe the problem is that the code loads before the jquery library. Try to put all your code inside the jQuery `ready` event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var boxWidth = $(window).width();
    // if mobile then we will keep width @ 100% else only 50%
    if (boxWidth > 768) {
        boxWidth = boxWidth * 0.50;
        console.log(boxWidth);
    }
    else boxWidth = boxWidth;

    $('#menu-open').on('click', function () {
        $('#slider').css('width', boxWidth);
        $('#slider').toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    })

    $('#menu-close').on('click', function () {
        $('#slider').css('width', 0);
        $('#slider').toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    })
});
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: If the code loads before the jquery library then it does not help wrapping it in a document ready, and then he would have gotten a jquery is not defined error.

Comment: Yes, thank you Stefanos! Wrapping this script like that fixed the problem and it works again :)